# Is my dataset unlearnable, or is my LSTM model not smart enough?

Tags: classification, long-short-term-memory, time-series, binary-classification

I have time-series data obtained from a video. The data is composed of bitrate and corresponding label pairs for each timestamp:

[image: dataset]

The distribution over the first 30 seconds is as follows:

[image: data distribution]

I have built an LSTM model for this dataset to be able to classify the labels based on the bitrate. However, it seems that my model is not able to learn. Validation accuracy starts from approximately 0.3 (makes sense, since I have 2 classes (log2 = 0.3)) and it does not improve.

Do you have any idea about this, is it normal considering this sample data distribution, or is something might be wrong with my model? Thanks!

Comment: well, what is your model and how are you training it?